# Duration in seconds the session lasts

Tags: r

i have a dataframe contain session start and end time

```
> data %>% group_by(SessionID) %>% summarise(start_time = min(Timestamp), end_time =max(Timestamp), unique_items=length(unique(ItemID)))
# A tibble: 1,815 x 4
   SessionID start_time              end_time                unique_items
       <int> <dttm>                  <dttm>                         <int>
 1        11 2014-04-03 11:04:11.417 2014-04-03 11:04:18.096            1
 2        12 2014-04-02 10:42:17.226 2014-04-02 10:42:17.226            1
 3        21 2014-04-07 09:24:18.306 2014-04-07 09:24:18.359            2
 4        22 2014-04-06 01:47:51.888 2014-04-06 01:47:51.888            1
 5        26 2014-04-06 16:44:58.482 2014-04-06 16:44:58.482            1
 6        33 2014-04-06 18:24:51.206 2014-04-06 18:24:51.426            3
 7        46 2014-04-03 06:07:19.921 2014-04-03 07:09:22.750            1
 8        87 2014-04-07 06:47:34.388 2014-04-07 06:57:22.802            8
 9       103 2014-04-03 14:26:27.706 2014-04-03 14:26:27.706            1
10       104 2014-04-07 18:31:45.755 2014-04-07 18:31:45.755            1
```

i want to convert da session end time to seconds and display result like this

```
    > result
    # A tibble: 1,815 x 2
   SessionID       end_time                   session end_time in seconds               
   <int>           <dttm>                 
     1        11 2014-04-03 11:04:18.096
     2        12 2014-04-02 10:42:17.226
     3        21 2014-04-07 09:24:18.359
     4        22 2014-04-06 01:47:51.888
     5        26 2014-04-06 16:44:58.482
     6        33 2014-04-06 18:24:51.426
     7        46 2014-04-03 07:09:22.750
     8        87 2014-04-07 06:57:22.802
     9       103 2014-04-03 14:26:27.706
    10       104 2014-04-07 18:31:45.755
    # ... with 1,805 more rows
```

and display duration in seconds the session lasts

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the time duration between the start and end in seconds, you can try this :

```
data %>% group_by(SessionID) %>% 
summarise(start_time = min(Timestamp), end_time =max(Timestamp)) %>% # using your code until here
mutate(`session end_time in seconds` = as.numeric(difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "secs"))) # gives the time interval in seconds
```